# can i call multiple activities simultaneously?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-activity

I'm making an app in which there are 7 check boxes and a submit button. 
Each check box is entitled to a separate activity which contains a set of tasks to be done. 
activities of the checked boxes needs to be called when the submit button is pressed.
Can I open multiple activities at once?

Comment: if there is background work your can start service.In android only one activity is at forground

Comment: But each activity will occupy the entire screen so there will be no point in opening multiple activities at once. You can use Fragments if you really want the user to do all the things at the same time

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to stack 7 activities one over each other at once.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can show only one Activity at time. You should use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) if you want to update your Activity based on what checkbox is clicked.

Another tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html), by reading this you'll learn how to let work your [main activity with fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).